# How to connect to remote spark cluster and execute jobs locally

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have deployed Spark Cluster using bitnami/spark helm chart. I have two worker node and one master node running. I want my application from anywhere to connect to spark cluster and execute jobs. How to achieve that ? My code:

```
package com.sompackage;

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import scala.collection.JavaConverters;


public class SparkTestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("sc://master-node-url:masterport")
                .appName("SparkPi")
                .config("spark.submit.deployMode","client")
                .config("spark.driver.host", "my-pub-ip")
                .config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "my-private-ip")
                .config("spark.driver.port", "1080")
                .config("spark.fileserver.port", "1081")
                .config("spark.broadcast.port", "1082")
                .config("spark.replClassServer.port", "1083")
                .config("spark.blockManager.port", "1084")
                .config("spark.executor.port", "1085")
                .getOrCreate();

        SparkContext sc = spark.sparkContext();

        int slices = (args.length == 1) ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 2;
        int n = 100 * slices;
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            l.add(i);
        }
        List<Integer> seqNumList = IntStream.rangeClosed(10, 20).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());


        RDD<Integer> numRDD = sc
                .parallelize(JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(seqNumList.iterator()).asScala()
                        .toSeq(), 2, scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Integer.class));


        numRDD.toJavaRDD().foreach(x -> System.out.println(x));

        spark.stop();
    }
}
```

The error that I am seeing:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.somepackage.SparkTestMain
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:71)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2034)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1898)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1704)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$FieldValues.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:2606)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2457)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2257)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1733)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2157)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1721)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$FieldValues.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:2606)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2457)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2257)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1733)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2157)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1721)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$FieldValues.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:2606)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2457)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2257)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1733)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2157)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1721)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$FieldValues.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:2606)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2457)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2257)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1733)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$FieldValues.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:2606)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2457)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2257)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1733)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:509)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:467)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
```

I tried changing java versions, different spark versions but could not make it work.

Comment: Have you started Spark server on your cluster? Also, did you have a chance to go through the [Use Spark Connect...](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-connect-overview.html#use-spark-connect-in-standalone-applications) and [What is supported...](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-connect-overview.html#what-is-supported-in-spark-34)?

Comment: Yes, infact the error I am getting from server's stdout.

Comment: Did you also have a chance to go through the links in my previous comment? Regarding support for Scala and Python only, usage of ClassFinder, etc. as well as this note: _"Scala: In Spark 3.5, Spark Connect supports most Scala APIs, including Dataset, functions, Column, Catalog and KeyValueGroupedDataset.
...UDFs are supported, by default for the shell and in standalone applications with additional set-up requirements.
...
APIs such as SparkContext and RDD are deprecated in all Spark Connect versions."_

Comment: Thank you, _APIs such as SparkContext and RDD are deprecated in all Spark Connect versions._ and spark-connect-server was not running. I am able to connect now. You can post your comment as an answer if you'd like to.

Comment: I think you answering your own question would make more sense, and will help others having similar issues.